# Querying a property that is in a deeply nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

So I have this document within the course collection

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("53580ff62e868947708073a9"),
    "startDate" : ISODate("2014-04-23T19:08:32.401Z"),
    "scoreId" : ObjectId("531f28fd495c533e5eaeb00b"),
    "rewardId" : null,
    "type" : "certificationCourse",
    "description" : "This is a description",
    "name" : "testingAutoSteps1",
    "authorId" : ObjectId("532a121e518cf5402d5dc276"),
    "steps" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "This is a step",
            "description" : "This is a description",
            "action" : "submitCategory",
            "value" : "532368bc2ab8b9182716f339",
            "statusId" : ObjectId("5357e26be86f746b68482c8a"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("53580ff62e868947708073ac"),
            "required" : true,
            "quantity" : 1,
            "userId" : [ 
                ObjectId("53554b56e3a1e1dc17db903f")
            ]
        },...
```

And I want to do is create a query that returns all courses that have a specific `userId` in the `userId` array that is in the `steps` array for a specific `userId`. I've tried using `$elemMatch` like so

```
Course.find({ 
    "steps": { 
        "$elemMatch": { 
            "userId": { 
                "$elemMatch": "53554b56e3a1e1dc17db903f"
            }
        }
    }
},
```

But It seems to be returning a empty document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) usage is not necessary unless you actually have compound sub-documents in that nested array element. And also is not necessary unless the value being referenced could possibly duplicate in another compound document.

Since this is an `ObjectId` we are talking about, then it's going to be unique, at least within this array. So just use the "dot-notation" form:

```
Course.find({
    "steps.userId": ObjectId("53554b56e3a1e1dc17db903f")
},
```

Go back and look at the [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) documentation. In this case, the direct "dot-notation" form is all you need

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work for you, you have the syntax off a bit plus you need to use ObjectId():

```
db.Course.find({ steps : { $elemMatch: { userId:ObjectId("53554b56e3a1e1dc17db903f")} } })
```

Comment: That will work, but you can simplify it to `Course.find({'steps.userId': '53554b56e3a1e1dc17db903f'})` because you're not comparing multiple fields per element.